# How does Meteor connect to Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Very new to Meteor.

I am trying to make a separate worker process that uses the `ddp` and `ddp-login` packages to log in to my main Meteor app's Mongo collections over DDP.

It is prompting for credentials.

My questions are:

- What are the default credentials Meteor sets up to connect to Mongo?
- Where are these located in the Meteor project? Where is the connection string?
- How do I change these credentials?

I have been hunting all over my project source and it's still "magical" to me.

Comment: Meteor start a simple Mongo server which does not require any credentials information to connect. The default port will be `webPort + 1`, for ex if your app is at `localhost:3000` then the Mongo url will be `localhost:3001`. If you want to use another Mongo server, you could simple specify the environment variable `MONGO_URL` value

Comment: To add to what Khang said: if you wanted to point to a mongodb that was set up independently of meteor then then set the MONGO_URL env var on your server. For development purposes you can just call it inline when you start your app `MONGO_URL=mongodb://username:password@your-mongo-server.domain.com:port/database_name meteor` where port is usually 27017.